# Selenium webdriver - execute_script on the browser that I'm currently in

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, robotframework

so I'm running some tests with Robot Framework in a Firefox webdriver.
During these tests, I need to do something like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from robot.api.deco import keyword
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn
from SeleniumLibrary import SeleniumLibrary


@keyword('Refresh Page Menu')
def refresh_page():
        # create webdriver object 
        driver = webdriver.Firefox() 
        driver.get("https://mytest.html") 
        # write script 
        script = "navigateTodiagram(305)"
       # generate a alert via javascript 
        driver.execute_script(script)
```

the thing is how can I do this with the web that I'm currently doing my tests on Robot Framework.
Instead of opening a new browser?
I want to execute_script("navigateTodiagram(305)") on the browser where I'm doing my tests.

Anyone has any ideas?
Thank you very much

Comment: That workflow is not supported by selenium.

Comment: Do you want to write your own JavaScript and execute it in current Selenium session?

Comment: @JaSON If that way works I can do it yes, I never worked with javascript tho. Do you have any ideas on how to implement it? Or any documentation that can help? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the doc of the SeleniumLibrary - there is a keyword precisely for that, [Execute Javascript](http://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Execute%20Javascript).

```
Execute Javascript    navigateTodiagram(305)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked :) do you know if I can get the result of a command if I do this way?

Comment: Yes, assign the output to a variable - e.g. `${my var}=    Execute Javascript   navigateTodiagram(305)`

Comment: thank you for your quick reply, I've noticed that :) but it's not possible to use that output variable as:  ` Execute Javascript      navigateTodiagram(${my var}) `, is it?

Comment: That case is also possible; when you put `${my var}` inside the js function argument, you should think - what type is expected there? If the function takes numbers, and the value of the variable will always be int/float, then `navigateTodiagram(${my var})` will work, RF will put the number value of the `${my var}` variable. But if the function expects a string, then you should surround it with quotes, so it's a valid one - `navigateTodiagram("${my var}")`, and doesn't break the JS syntax.

Comment: Thank you again for your reply, I tried but it didn't work. The result of the command is an int. What I've noticed is that by doing this: ${my var}=    Execute Javascript   MYAPP.current_navigation_hash , nothing it's saved on the variable. Do you know why? Thank you

Comment: The keyword returns whatever the JS function does; if the js doesn't return, the value of `${my var}` should be `None` (the python data type). By the way, you typed "MYAPP.current_navigation_hash" - without brackets, which is not the proper way to call a function in js.

Comment: Well, the thing is when I write the command MYAPP.current_navigation_hash on the console it gives me a number. But when I try to do it with ${my var}= Execute Javascript MYAPP.current_navigation_hash , it's not getting the value instead it gives me a None variable :(

Comment: Ok I figured it out, I have to put like this:  ${id_page}=   Execute Javascript   return (MYAPP.current_navigation_hash) . It was missing the return :)

Comment: Very well, I'm glad it did :)